# Group By Two Tables

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables with identical schema. I want to get a count of all the people with a given surname in both tables, and have found I can do it like this:

```
SELECT surname, count(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT surname
    FROM people.NorthKorea
    UNION ALL
    SELECT surname
    FROM peopleGlobal.NorthKorea
) AS t
GROUP BY surname
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

This is fine for small tables, but I have tables with up to 250 million rows, so was wondering if there may be a more efficient way of doing this? Such as INSERTING the result of the COUNT from one table into a table, and then updating / inserting (REPLACE?) the result of the COUNT on the second table.

N.B. I actually want to store the result of the COUNT on both tables in another table.

Comment: Why would you store the count in a table? You would have to update it anytime the surnames change.. Seems like a bad idea

Comment: The two source tables are lists of people who live in North Korea. They won't be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index on the surname column should help a lot. I would try with this query, if there are a lot more rows than surnames I expect it to run faster:

```
SELECT surname, SUM(cnt)
FROM
(
   SELECT surname, COUNT(*) as cnt
   FROM people.NorthKorea
   GROUP BY surname
   UNION ALL
   SELECT surname, COUNT(*) as cnt
   FROM peopleGlobal.NorthKorea
   GROUP BY surname
)
GROUP BY surname
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried my query on 4 million rows - it took 146 seconds; yours took 2.75. I will accept in a few mins when SO allows me. *Are time-restrictions on accepting answers universal, or is it just me?*